# Throwing warning while navigating to another screen from MKMapView in IOS

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, warnings

I have dropped multiple annotations on MKMapView. When I navigate to another screen from map its showing warning. And because of warning sometimes my app is crashing randomly. Below is my code by which is have dropped annotations on Map View.

```
[annView addObserver:self
                      forKeyPath:Identifier
                         options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                         context:(__bridge void *)(GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED)];
```

And below is the error I am getting
An instance 0x207308c0 of class MyAnnotationView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on `NSKVODeallocateBreak` to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:

```
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x20182420> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x201823e0: Observer: 0x1dfac080, Key path: selected, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x2d3908, Property: 0x1a47ce80>
```

Comment: Why are you using KVO to observe the annotation view?  What is the value of Identifier?  If you need to know if an annotation is selected, why not use the didSelectAnnotationView delegate method instead?  Anyway, are you calling removeObserver to match the addObserver?